# What are the main applications of functional analysis to numerical analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, soft-question, applications

I'm trying to improve my understanding of real/complex analysis and functional analysis because I've seen there're a lot of relationships with numerical analysis (as instance interpolation generalized).

However I was wondering what are the main applications results that functional analysis could apply to numerical analysis, in function approximation specifically?

Comment: Are you interested the approximation of PDE's ?

Comment: Not specifically, but i know the theory of Sobolev space applied there. What i was looking for is something interpolation generalized, and what kind of properties can you derive using the framework of functional analysis. Or regression/extrapolation and what kind of properties you can derive in that case.

Comment: Maybe interesting for you: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441904577, http://ccom.ucsd.edu/~mholst/pubs/notes/analysis.pdf.